# What are alternatives to using IQueryable<T> in Repository Pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, iqueryable

I am ASP.NET MVC newbie (but .NET experienced dev) and I am trying to learn how to properly set web application infrastructure. 
Repository pattern is what I am copping these days and after reading dozens of blogs/articles/answers in the past few days I am still not sure how to use it the right way. I am learning from the [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 Adam Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361) and here is the code for repository interface based on this book:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    void Add(T newEntity);
    void Remove(T entity);

    T FindById(long id);
}
```

After more research online I realized that many people think that returning IQueryable from repository is bad practice and I can (mostly) understand why. However, I can't seem to find answer on what exactly is the alternative? I know about idea of having a custom repository, for each entity, that has specialized method for each possible query which would basically return IEnumerable and not IQueryable... but this just doesn't seem right to me (it's not elegant solution, too many code writing and possible code redundancy etc...).

What are other alternatives?

Comment: When I implement the repository pattern, I write methods that return Lists of objects, for example, in your example I would create a method signature List<T> ReadAll();

Comment: Ok but that is not very flexible if I want to perform more complex queries in my MVC controller such as for example paging feature.

Comment: If you needed more complex queries, you would add more methods to your repository which took parameters, performed more complex queries with those parameters, but still returned a list of objects....I will write an example below....

Comment: I prefer generic repositories that return `IQueryable<T>`. I can then chain those repository methods inside services. The service layer will return `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Jasen Please read this about repository and IQueryable http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/01/24/Repository-Pattern-and-IQueryable.aspx

Comment: OP, just to make sure things are clear: Asp Net Mvc deals with web apps, EF is an ORM, Repository is a design pattern unrelated to a technology or language and usable in any application whether it's web or not.

Answer (score 7):

You have two alternatives.

## Specification pattern

The first one is to use the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). You create a set of classes which are used to limit the search result.

The wikipedia article is a bit poor since it doesn't show how to write business specifications (i.e. "real" specifications). But you basically use the lower level specs (And/Or etc) inside your business specs.

By doing so you can have simpler repository classes and instead code those specifications.

## Specific repositories.

Create a repository for every root aggregate (Order, User etc).  Each repository have unique query methods that apply to the specific business requirements.

The user repository could have for instance

```
IPagedResult<User> FindDisabledUser(int pageNumber, int pageSize);
```

And the order repository could have

```
IPagedResult<User> GetOrdersReadyForShipping(DateTime orderAfterThisDate);
```

---

I've written a set of data layer articles: http://blog.gauffin.org/tag/data-access/. One of those also explains why it's not a good idea to expose `IQueryable<T>` in your repositories.

Comment: Is there any good example of specification pattern in .NET that would allow me to have fluid expressions for queries like in LINQ? Eg. something like: Where().OrderBy().Skip()?

Comment: If you REALLY want to use the fluent approach, you can use directly Expressions like Linq, but YOU'll have to transform them into SQL.

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment underneath the original question, this is how I would implement a repository needing more complex query requirements. I have also included my DbContext object for the Entity Framework.

I like this pattern because it hides the Entity Framework implementation behind the repository ensuring that the Entity Framework is not tightly coupled with your application.

```
public class PersonRepository: IPersonRepository
{
    public List<Person> ReadAll()
    {
        using (var context = new EfContext())
            return context.Persons.ToList();
    }

    public List<Person> ReadPage(int pageIndex, int itemCount)
    {
        using (var context = new EfContext())
            return context.Persons
                          .Skip(pageIndex * itemCount)
                          .Take(itemCount)
                          .ToList();

    }

    public List<Person> ReadAllWhoseNamesStartWith(string nameExpression)
    {
        using (var context = new EfContext())
            return context.Persons
                          .Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(nameExpression)
                          .ToList();
    }

    public List<Person> ReadAllWhoseFavouriteColorIs(string color)
    {
        using (var context = new EfContext())
            return context.Persons
                          .Where(r => r.FavoriteColor.StartsWith(color)
                          .ToList();
    }
}

public class EfContext: DbContext
{
    public EfContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Houses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EfContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: While there are multiple variations on what the repo interface should look like, the idea is the same. Who doesn't want to use long descriptive name will use Criteria objects as method arguments. The important thing to understand is that repository abstracts persistence in ANY form to deal with application (business) objects as opposed to data objects (ORM entities or other DAO). Most of the confusion comes up when there is no difference between business objects and data objects. In that case the repository might help but most of the time is just an useless abstraction

Comment: I disagree that the repository is ever a useless distraction. If all repository classes implement an interface and I use an IOC container to resolve them, it is very easy for me to mock those repositories when writing unit tests, something that isn't possible when programming directly against an entity framework dbcontext.

Comment: It depends on the app. EVER is an absolute. While I'm using Repository as much as I can, sometimes it really doesn't bring any value. It could be 1% of cases, but it can happen. WE're not zealots here, Repository is a tool and it doesn't look like a hammer to me.

Comment: The person asking the original question was effectively inviting us to be opinionated about how we use the repository pattern, which I have been. I have also been careful to use words like 'I' and 'Me' when describing how I am implementing the pattern and the reasons why. I believe that I made a good point about using the repository pattern extensively for mocking in order to increase unit test coverage. Please, respond to that point rather than getting angry. I am not a zealot, but sometimes I am opinionated when asked to be. That can be a good thing in stackoverflow.

Comment: Angry? I was the first to upvote your anwser, this means I agree.  The point is, that IN MY OPINION, sometimes you don't need it and you don't need unit tests either. Let's face it, the majority of web apps using repository are simple CRUD and are using the Repoistory because it's the trend to do so (they saw it in the MS tutorials about asp.net mvc) hence the usage of the wrong generic repository on top of EF.

Comment: Fair enough, I apologize if I misunderstood your intention. Choosing not to use the repository pattern and the reasons that you have pointed out is a valid and valuable answer to the original question. For the benefit of anyone reading the question and evaluating the options regarding the repository pattern, I think you should post your opinion as one of the answers.